# Join 2 queries with equal fields created dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, dynamically-generated

I have a table that i wanted to create some charts.
Basically i need to know how many registers i have in interval of 10 minutes and how many of them are already pos-processed. With this 2 queries i have the info i need, but i need they 2 in just 1 result table.

First query

```
SELECT  
    (
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora) AS NVARCHAR) +
        ':' +
        CAST((DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6) AS NVARCHAR) +
        '0'         
    )                                       AS Hora,
    COUNT(*)                                AS Movimentações
FROM
    Integracao m
WHERE
        m.Ocr_DataHora      >=  '2012-09-17 00:00:00.000'
    AND m.Ocr_DataHora      <   '2012-09-18 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY        
    DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6)
ORDER BY    
    DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6)
```

Second query

```
SELECT  
    (
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, s.Ocr_DataHora) AS NVARCHAR) +
        ':' +
        CAST((DATEPART(MINUTE, s.Ocr_DataHora) % 6) AS NVARCHAR) +
        '0'         
    )                                       AS Hora,
    COUNT(*)                                AS Sucesso
FROM
    Integracao s
WHERE
        s.Veiculo_Modelo    <>  ''
    AND s.Ocr_DataHora      >=  '2012-09-17 00:00:00.000'
    AND s.Ocr_DataHora      <   '2012-09-18 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY        
    DATEPART(HOUR, s.Ocr_DataHora),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, s.Ocr_DataHora) % 6)
```

How can i join them if my common field is generated dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already told you, you could just use the two queries as derived tables (subselects) and join them using each one's `Hora` column. It doesn't matter if the column is computed in the query, it's perfectly legal to use it in a join condition.

However, I think you can get the same results more efficiently, by calculating both counts in a single query (i.e. without subqueries). Here's how you can do that:

```
SELECT  
    (
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora) AS NVARCHAR) +
        ':' +
        CAST((DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6) AS NVARCHAR) +
        '0'         
    )                                                  AS Hora,
    COUNT(*)                                           AS Movimentações,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Veiculo_Modelo <> '' THEN 1 END) AS Sucesso
FROM
    Integracao m
WHERE
        m.Ocr_DataHora      >=  '2012-09-17 00:00:00.000'
    AND m.Ocr_DataHora      <   '2012-09-18 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY        
    DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6)
ORDER BY    
    DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6)
```

As you can see, the query doesn't filter rows on `s.Veiculo_Modelo <> ''`. However, that condition is used when counting rows for the `Sucesso` column. The argument of the second `COUNT` is a CASE expression. It returns a value (arbitrarily chosen to be `1`, but could be anything really) if the specified condition is met and `NULL` otherwise. Since `COUNT` omits nulls, the result will be the same as with your dedicated query calculating and returning `Sucesso`.

Comment: I really never though i can do an case statement in count! :O Even in the documentation nothing is mentioned!!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the output to be as follows:

```
Hora | Movimentações | Sucesso
```

You can use the two SQL queries as if they are table using the `WITH` statement as follows:

```
WITH 
firstQuery(Hora, Movimentações) AS (<first query definition with out ORDER BY >),
secondQuery(Hora, Sucesso) AS (<second query definition with out ORDER BY >)
SELECT
     f.Hora, f.Movimentações , s.Sucesso
FROM 
    firstQuery f
    JOIN secondQuery s
    ON f.Hora = s.Hora
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by putting them in a sub query in a from clause. The way I'm referring to has the following form:

```
Select A.Hora,A.Movimentações,B.Sucesso
From (*First Query*) as A
inner join (*Second Query*) as B on A.Hora = B.Hora
```

The end result being:

```
Select A.Hora,A.Movimentações,B.Sucesso
From (SELECT  
    (
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora) AS NVARCHAR) +
        ':' +
        CAST((DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6) AS NVARCHAR) +
        '0'         
    )                                       AS Hora,
    COUNT(*)                                AS Movimentações
FROM
    Integracao m
WHERE
        m.Ocr_DataHora      >=  '2012-09-17 00:00:00.000'
    AND m.Ocr_DataHora      <   '2012-09-18 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY        
    DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6)
ORDER BY    
    DATEPART(HOUR, m.Ocr_DataHora),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, m.Ocr_DataHora) % 6)) As A
inner join (SELECT  
    (
        CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, s.Ocr_DataHora) AS NVARCHAR) +
        ':' +
        CAST((DATEPART(MINUTE, s.Ocr_DataHora) % 6) AS NVARCHAR) +
        '0'         
    )                                       AS Hora,
    COUNT(*)                                AS Sucesso
FROM
    Integracao s
WHERE
        s.Veiculo_Modelo    <>  ''
    AND s.Ocr_DataHora      >=  '2012-09-17 00:00:00.000'
    AND s.Ocr_DataHora      <   '2012-09-18 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY        
    DATEPART(HOUR, s.Ocr_DataHora),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, s.Ocr_DataHora) % 6)) As B on B.Hora = A.Hora
```